# The Session object is null in ASP.NET MVC 5 webapplication once deployed to IIS 8.5 (W 2012 R2)

Tags: asp.net, session, iis

My application is in MVC 5 and it runs fine on VS2019. It was also running fine on Windows Server 2012 R2 IIS 8.5 , until someone rebuilt that server and everything was lost. I again installed iis 8.5 on that server, took code from production server(this server is also 2012 R2 iis 8.5). But now, session variables are loosing their value. Same code is running fine on production server. I have used same web.config, but its not working on newly created server.
Session state is set to "In Process".

HttpContext.Current.Session[$"IsDbTypeSelected"] returns null(only on newly created server).

I have also tried following solutions and added this in my web.config, but nothing seems to work.

```
<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
            <remove name="Session" />
            <add name="Session" type="System.Web.SessionState.SessionStateModule, System.Web, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
</modules>

<pages enableSessionState="true" />
```

Following is my complete web.config file

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.web.extensions>
    <scripting>
      <webServices>
        <jsonSerialization maxJsonLength="1000000" />
      </webServices>
    </scripting>
  </system.web.extensions> 
  <connectionStrings configSource="Config\ConnectionStrings_QA.config"></connectionStrings>
  <appSettings configSource="Config\appSettings_QA.config"></appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <globalization culture="en-GB" uiCulture="en-GB" enableClientBasedCulture="false" />
    <compilation targetFramework="4.6">
    </compilation>
    <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="40960" targetFramework="4.5" executionTimeout="5000" />
    <authentication mode="Windows" />

    <sessionState cookieless="UseCookies" cookieName="ASP.NET_SessionId" mode="InProc" timeout="480" />
    <pages enableSessionState="true" />

    <authorization>
      <deny users="?" />
    </authorization>
    <customErrors defaultRedirect="~/Shared/Error" mode="Off">
      <error statusCode="404" redirect="~/Shared/Error" />
    </customErrors>
        <httpCookies httpOnlyCookies="false" />
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>

    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
    <remove name="Session" />
    <add name="Session" type="System.Web.SessionState.SessionStateModule, System.Web,Version=2.0.0.0,Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
    </modules>

    <staticContent>
      <remove fileExtension=".woff" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".woff" mimeType="application/x-font-woff" />
      <remove fileExtension=".woff2" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".woff2" mimeType="application/font-woff2" />
    </staticContent>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
    <handlers>
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
      <remove name="OPTIONSVerbHandler" />
      <remove name="TRACEVerbHandler" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="*" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Optimization" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-1.1.0.0" newVersion="1.1.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="WebGrease" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.6.5135.21930" newVersion="1.6.5135.21930" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Helpers" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-5.2.3.0" newVersion="5.2.3.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Antlr3.Runtime" publicKeyToken="eb42632606e9261f" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.5.0.2" newVersion="3.5.0.2" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-10.0.0.0" newVersion="10.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
  <system.codedom>
    <compilers>
      <compiler language="c#;cs;csharp" extension=".cs" type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.CSharpCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=1.0.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:6 /nowarn:1659;1699;1701" />
      <compiler language="vb;vbs;visualbasic;vbscript" extension=".vb" type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.VBCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=1.0.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:14 /nowarn:41008 /define:_MYTYPE=\&quot;Web\&quot; /optionInfer+" />
    </compilers>
  </system.codedom>
  <location path="Applets">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="?" />
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
</configuration>
```

Comment: After you remove and add SessionStateModule, have you restarted your iis and try again?

Comment: I have reset it now, but it same error occurred.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to add the following method into global.asax.cs, then check whether the session object is null.

```
protected void Application_PostAuthorizeRequest()
{
    HttpContext.Current.SetSessionStateBehavior(SessionStateBehavior.Required);
}
```